# Как передать в variable type класс который лежит в папке app->debug?

Tags: android, xml, graphql, android-data-binding, apollo-client

Разрабатываю приложение на android. В разработке использую библиотеку Apllo для работы с GraphQL. У меня есть модели, которые Apollo генерирует автоматически, их я хочу использовать в xml для работы с DataBinding, но проблема в том что я не могу прописать в xml variable type эту модель так как она лежит в папке app -> build.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Подскажите как прописать путь до этой модели.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разверните папку `src/main/graphQL`, в зависимости как у вас в проекте лежит `schema JSON`, apollo сгенерирует пакет для модели.

Либо как-то так: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46934473/5479247
Либо как в документации: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/android/essentials/get-started/#generating-models-from-your-queries

Под рукой нет проекта проверить. По полному пути думаю сможете добавить класс в DataBinding xml.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Все получилось:)